# Buttons not disappearing after clicking them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have the following code, which renders 2 buttons at a time based on the user's query, example: 'Yes' and 'No'. The goal is that once the user clicks either of the buttons, they should both disappear. I tried to add a set state component as follows:

```
export default class Reply extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {  
        this.setState(state => ({      
             isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn   
          }));  }

    render() {
        if(this.state.isToggleOn === 'ON'){
        return (
            <Button
                tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex}
                style={this.props.styles.default}
                onClick={this.handleClick}
                hoverStyle={this.props.styles.hover}
            >
                {this.props.text}
                {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
            </Button>
        )
    } else {
      return null;
}
```

}
Currently, the buttons don't disappear when I click on them as well as show 'ON' and 'OFF' with the button text as well example: 'YesON' and 'NoOFF' . When I click them, the 'ON' changes to 'OFF' and vice versa each time but the buttons do not disappear.

Can someone explain where I'm going wrong and how to fix this

Comment: you should check this.state.isToggleOn before returning a <Button> and return null instead if it's off.

Comment: You are not adding the logic for button hide ?

Comment: Thanks, I added my logic but now the buttons simply don't appear because I never set it to 'ON'..

Comment: @hello_world where's the **2nd button**?

Comment: They are rendered dynamically from the user's query from an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Conditional rendering

The button doesn’t disappear because it's still being rendered. In order to have it rendered conditionally, you need to specify a condition on basis of which it would hide and display. You can read more about it in the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

```
render() {
  const { isToggleOn } = this.state

  return (
    <>
      {isToggleOn && (
        <Button
          tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex}
          className={styles.quickReply}
          style={this.props.styles.default}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          hoverStyle={this.props.styles.hover}
        >
          {this.props.text}
          ON
        </Button>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is giving me a syntax error at 'isToggleOn && ' saying it expects a comma, but adding a comma doesn't fix the error either

Comment: @hello_world you have not added the closing braces for render function and the component in your update answer. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
         render() {
                    return (
  {this.state.isToggleOn ?
                        <Button
                            tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex}
                            style={this.props.styles.default}

                            onClick={this.handleClick}
                            hoverStyle={this.props.styles.hover}
                           className={styles.quickReply}
                        >
                            {this.props.text}
                            {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
                        </Button>
:<div></div>
         
                    )
                }
```

Comment: Hello this is giving me a syntax error for "this.state.isToggleOn ?" at the this.state part, saying it should be this:state instead

Comment: Another solution is to use the brush className for button

Comment: `className={this.state.isToggleOn ? "" :"offStyle"}`

Comment: `.offStyle{
   display: none;
}`

Comment: Is it possible to edit this into the answer? I'm not sure how to incorporate it otherwise because it gives me the error mentioned in my first reply

Comment: I can't have {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'} inside the Button tag because then it shows up next to the button name as well, as mentioned in my question :/ it doesn't work right now the buttons don't disappear after I click them

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your problem , this workaround would be easy to implement using the latest version of react,

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react'


export const Button = () => {
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(true);
    const handleclick = ()=>{
        setActive(false);
    }
    return (
        (isActive)?
        <div>
            <button onClick = {(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); handleclick()}}>
                Sample Button
            </button>
        </div>:<></>
    )
}
```

Using the "useState" will help you keep the code cleaner, and can be easily changed to different states,

Happy Coding :)